# How to modify sharpness damage in minecraft 1.12.2

Tags: java, minecraft

How can I change the damage of the enchant sharpness in minecraft 1.12.2? I have tried this method but I don't understand how to go on

````
   private RubySharpnessFixer plugin;
   public EnchantmentWeaponDamageCustom(RubySharpnessFixer plugin, Rarity rarity, int i, EnumItemSlot... enumItemSlots) {
       super(rarity, i, enumItemSlots);
       this.plugin = plugin;
   }
   public float a(int i, EnumMonsterType enummonstertype) {
       return (this.a == 0) ? (float)(Math.max(1, i) * plugin.getConfig().getDouble("damage-per-level")) : ((this.a == 1 && enummonstertype == EnumMonsterType.UNDEAD) ? (i * 2.5F) : ((this.a == 2 && enummonstertype == EnumMonsterType.ARTHROPOD) ? (i * 2.5F) : 0.0F));
   }

   public boolean hook() {
       EnchantmentWeaponDamageCustom enchantmentWeaponDamageCustom = new EnchantmentWeaponDamageCustom(plugin, Rarity.COMMON, 16, EnumItemSlot.MAINHAND);
   }
} ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is multiple ways :

#### 1. In-game: Command

`attribute @s minecraft:generic.attack_damage modifier add 0-0-0-0-0 attribute_name .25 add`

(replace the `0-0-0-0-0` by a valid UUID)

There is a [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/MinecraftCommands/comments/htx8a7/comment/fyk1q1k) that explain it.

But I think it's not what you are looking for.

#### 2. Plugin: NMS & reflection

Firstly, you have to change the enchant currently registered. Such as it's not authorized by default, we have to use reflection.

```java
// import
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_12_R1.enchantments.CraftEnchantment;
import org.bukkit.enchantments.Enchantment;
// now the code :
try {
    Enchantment enchantToChange = Enchantment.DAMAGE_ALL; // the enchant that we want to change
    // SharpnessModifier is a class that is showed after
    SharpnessModifier sharpness = new SharpnessModifier(0);
    net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.Enchantment.enchantments.a(16, new MinecraftKey("sharpness"), sharpness); // add enchants to NMS class
    CraftEnchantment newEnchant = new CraftEnchantment(sharpness);
    
    Field byNameField = Enchantment.class.getDeclaredField("byName"); // enchant by name
    byNameField.setAccessible(true);
    Map<String, Enchantment> byName = (Map<String, Enchantment>) byNameField.get(null);
    byName.put(enchantToChange.getName(), newEnchant);
    
    Field byIdField = Enchantment.class.getDeclaredField("byId"); // enchant by ID
    byIdField.setAccessible(true);
    Map<Integer, Enchantment> byId = (Map<Integer, Enchantment>) byIdField.get(null);
    byId.put(enchantToChange.getId(), newEnchant);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Then, you have to create a new class that will manage all rules that you want to define for this enchant.

```java
import net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.EnchantmentWeaponDamage;
import net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.EnumMonsterType;
import net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.ItemStack;

public class SharpnessModifier extends EnchantmentWeaponDamage {

    public SharpnessModifier(int i){
        super(Rarity.COMMON, i);
    }
    
    @Override
    public int getMaxLevel() {
        return 200;
    }
   
    @Override
    public float a(int i, EnumMonsterType enumMonsterType){
        // it's here that you will have what you want. You can calculate the damage
        // default calculation :
        /*
        if (a == 0)
            return (float) i * 5.0F;
        if (a == 1 && enumMonsterType == EnumMonsterType.UNDEAD)
            return (float) i * 2.5F;
        if (a == 2 && enumMonsterType == EnumMonsterType.ARTHROPOD)
            return (float) i * 2.5F;
        else
            return 0.0F;
        */
        return Float.MAX_VALUE; // max damage, just to try. I just OS a wither
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean canEnchant(ItemStack item) {
        return true; // allow for all item
    }
}
```

#### 3. Plugin: Damage event

This can also be done with packet.

You have to intercept damage event, and change damage value if player have sharpness.

```java
@EventHandler
public void a(EntityDamageByEntityEvent e) {
    if(e.getDamager() instanceof Player) {
        Player p = (Player) e.getDamager();
        ItemStack item = p.getItemInHand();
        if(item.containsEnchantment(Enchantment.DAMAGE_ALL)) {
            // manage damage with "e.setDamage(damage);"
        }
    }
}
```

It's not a very good solution because other things can interact with damage: critical, time (1.9+ pvp) ...

Comment: I tried the second method but it doesn't seem to work, when I try to enchant an object with sharpness it says "unknown enchant

Comment: the import that I used are the same, but it doesn't work. For example, if I try to enchant the pickaxe with essentials (/ enchant sharpness 1) it doesn't find the enchant

Comment: Oh, i didn't tried with essentials. I suggest you to try without it

Comment: I try with "/minecraft:enchant H3r0HD_ sharpness 1" but it does not add the enchant

Comment: Oh yes, sorry I forgot a line. Update: answer edited